# Unable to open devtools in profile mode for flutter web

Tags: flutter

I am able to run my flutter mobile application in profile mode. But when I try to run my flutter web application in profile mode, the dev tools are not open. I want to check the performance analyses of flutter web also.
So any option to analyze the performance of flutter web application?